# How to align text of Tkinter ttk widgets to the top? Resp. how to prevent the text from moving after rescaling?

Tags: python, tkinter, alignment, font-size, ttk

Everytime I rescale my window, the text starts to "move to the bottom" of the widget. How can I stop this behaviour? Here are 2 screenshots:

This is how it is not supposed to look like:
[image: the text moves to the bottom wehn the font becomes smaller]

I want the smaller font to be aligned as in this example with the initial font size (12)
[image: This is the desired behaviour with smaller font]

**MWE:**

```
import tkinter as tk 
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk


class MWE():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.master = window
        self.master.geometry('1920x1080')
        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.mainframe.pack()
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.font_resize) 
        
        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helevicta", size=12)
        
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.mainframe, values=('This text vanishes...', 1,2,3),  font=self.customFont)
        self.combobox.current(0)
        
        self.combobox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        
        self.label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='The label text not', font=self.customFont)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1)
    def font_resize(self, event):
        if self.mainframe.winfo_height() != event.width or self.mainframe.winfo_width() != event.height:
            calc_size=(self.master.winfo_height()*1e-5*self.master.winfo_width())+1 # some random formula to compute a font size dependent on the window's size
            int_size=int(calc_size)
            self.customFont['size'] = int_size

root=tk.Tk()

Var=MWE(root)
root.mainloop()
```

(I reposted this question because I forgot to include a MWE originally...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why the `ttk.Label` adjusts automatically whenever the `tkFont.Font`'s size is changed, but the `tkk.Combobox` doesn't. Fortunately a fairly simple workaround for that anomaly is to update the `font` option of the combobox *manually* whenever the font is changed.

**Off-topic:** When you bind `'<Configure>'` events to a root or toplevel window, it's also automatically bound to every widget it contains. This means that your `font_resize()` (renamed `on_resize()` below) method is unnecessarily being called multiple times when the window is resized — mostly harmless in this case but still redundant and a waste of processor time. To minimize any potential impact it might be having, I've also modified the beginning of the callback method so it filters-out these extraneous calls and prevents the rest of the method's code from executing.

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkFont
from tkinter import ttk


class MWE():
    def __init__(self, window):
        self.master = window
        self.master.geometry('1920x1080')
        self.master.bind('<Configure>', self.on_resize)

        self.mainframe = tk.Frame(self.master)
        self.mainframe.pack()

        self.customFont = tkFont.Font(family="Helevicta", size=12)
        self.combobox = ttk.Combobox(self.mainframe,
                                     values=('This text vanishes...', 1, 2, 3),
                                     font=self.customFont)
        self.combobox.current(0)
        self.combobox.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.label = ttk.Label(self.mainframe, text='The label text not',
                               font=self.customFont)
        self.label.grid(row=0, column=1)

        self.master.mainloop()

    def on_resize(self, event):
        if (event.widget == self.master and  # Ignore calls for children. ADDED.
            (self.master.winfo_height() != event.width
             or self.master.winfo_width() != event.height)
           ):
            # Compute window size dependent font size.
            calc_size = event.height * 1e-5 * event.width + 1
            self.customFont['size'] = int(calc_size)
            self.combobox['font'] = self.customFont  # ADDED.


MWE(tk.Tk())
```

Comment: I can't express how thankful I am for your advices and even beyond that you improved my code. Thanks a lot.